# Altering scroll speed in Linux in MacOSX

Tags: linux, macos, scroll

I often write fairly long one liners, such as the following from today:

```
zcat masterVarBeta-GS000022122-ASM.tsv.gz | awk '(""==$1){$1="#"}(">locus"==$1){$1="#>locus"}{print $0}' | head -n 1000 | bgzip -c > test22122.tsv.gz ; tabix -c "#" -0 -s 3 -b 4 -e 5 test22122.tsv.gz
```

If I error and discover the error is in the middle of the statement, I have to scroll all the way space by space.

If the scroll speed were set fairly high, this would still be reasonably rapid, however the default setting on this Mac appears to be very very slow.

How can I change the delay time before subsequent scroll when holding the <- or -> key in Terminal?

Finally, if there are (even more) advanced options for the way to scroll through in Terminal, where might I find the equivalent of a man page to read about that?

In Terminal --> preferences these settings *do not* appear to be found

Edit:

I found this under System Preferences --> Keyboard --> Scroll speed.

However, I am still interested in the larger question of whether there exist more advanced ways of "getting around" on the command line.

Comment: In OS X 10.11.5 this option is called "Key Repeat".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

control-A = beginning of line

control-E = end of line

option-arrows = forward or backwards one word at a time. This is the one that really makes the difference.

Comment: the option-arrows -- thats exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. You may have just saved me days total, a half-second at a time. thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I wonder how many days I've saved, a half-second at a time. Probably a few.